# Caching configuration table

Tags: java, caching, dictionary, ehcache

I have table with configurations which should be cached. 
I load that table only once on app start
All data will not be modified and will be used read only
So question do I need some cache like Ehcache or some static Map will be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I n my opinion a static map will be enough. (in my applications usually i use this method for application global configuration).

But this is my approach.